# Special kind of permutation

Tags: python, list

I am working on some code to produce all possible permutations from a list. Such products are constrained exclusively to one specific size. My code works for regular permutations, but I do not know how to obtain permutations that follow this type of logic. I'm supposed to get all of the permutations that follow this sort of criss-cross pattern, where the first element is followed by another element and then repeated until the product reaches size z, into one big array.
For example, given an array like `[0,1,2,3]` and `z=3`,
One should return something like `[[0,1,0][1,0,1][2,0,2][0,2,0][0,3,0][0,4,0]...]`
Of course the output would change based on z, so, if we had `z=4` the array would have subarrays that are of size 4, like `[[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[2,0,2,0],[0,2,0,2], etc.]`
Fundamentally, you just need to alternate two elements in the original array so they form that type of a-b/a-b-a/a-b-a-b/pattern, so two elements at a time are taken.
This is my code for basic permutations with size z.

```
def comb(k,array):
if k<=0:
    return [[]]
else:
    final=[]
    for part in comb(k-1,array):
        for e in array:
            final.append([e]+part)
        return final
```

I don't want to use any library because I am studying recursion specifically and that would be sort of pointless learning-wise. Thank you.

Comment: Cartesian products and permutations are very different things. It's like asking a math question but using the words "addition" and "multiplication" interchangeable. I have honestly no idea what you want your resulting list to look like. Can you produce some sample input and output that may better express your intentions?

Comment: You're right. I meant permutations, not cartesian products. The input is provided in the example :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

lst = [0,1,2,3]

result = list(product(lst,repeat=3))
```

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 3), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 0), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to not import anything because I'm working on recursion specifically

Answer (score 0):

Try `permutations` from `itertools` module:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
z = 3
out = list(permutations(l, r=z))
print(out)

# Output:
[(0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 2, 1),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 3, 1),
 (0, 3, 2),
 (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 0, 3),
 (1, 2, 0),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 0),
 (1, 3, 2),
 (2, 0, 1),
 (2, 0, 3),
 (2, 1, 0),
 (2, 1, 3),
 (2, 3, 0),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (3, 0, 1),
 (3, 0, 2),
 (3, 1, 0),
 (3, 1, 2),
 (3, 2, 0),
 (3, 2, 1)]
```

Check the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) of `permutations` which is roughly equivalent.

For `z=4`:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
z = 4
out = list(permutations(l, r=z))
print(out)

# Output:
[(0, 1, 2, 3),
 (0, 1, 3, 2),
 (0, 2, 1, 3),
 (0, 2, 3, 1),
 (0, 3, 1, 2),
 (0, 3, 2, 1),
 (1, 0, 2, 3),
 (1, 0, 3, 2),
 (1, 2, 0, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 0),
 (1, 3, 0, 2),
 (1, 3, 2, 0),
 (2, 0, 1, 3),
 (2, 0, 3, 1),
 (2, 1, 0, 3),
 (2, 1, 3, 0),
 (2, 3, 0, 1),
 (2, 3, 1, 0),
 (3, 0, 1, 2),
 (3, 0, 2, 1),
 (3, 1, 0, 2),
 (3, 1, 2, 0),
 (3, 2, 0, 1),
 (3, 2, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not follow the pattern and I am trying to learn recursion properly, so without itertools. I have made an edit about it in my post.